# How can I express these concepts using a single word?

Tags: vocabulary

I need help with few English words. I'm writing the article about online services and I am stuck. How to say using one word:

a) a person who posts a job (like a person who writes an advert on Freelancer.com) for example: I need a graphic designer or a babysitter etc

b) a person who offers the services for example: I am a cheap plumber and I can do ... but also I can cook for you delicious dinner etc (I believe it's not a tradesman)

c) noun- an order for someone to do something and get paid ( commission or errand?).

Comment: You're writing _an_ article about online services. _the article_ implies that there's only one (or that after your article is published, all the rest would become irrelevant).

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear if you want one word for each of a), b) and c) or a single word for the lot. If the second, you're in trouble right away, because a) and b) are people and c) is an abstraction.

Someone who hires free labour on a contract basis could be a "principal" or "client". If someone is a principal, the other one is his "agent". You won't see this among low-level tradesmen though.

The second could be "service provider", but be warned that this is *also* a respectful punter's term for his prostitute.

"Commission" certainly, especially in the graphic design field, but I would expect a babysitter to refer to just "a job".

"Errand", most certainly **not**, it has a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use market terms as *client* or *supplier*, what about :

1. Job offerer
2. Job fulfiller
3. Job agreement

Answer (score 0):

The places where all these types of requests and offers are collected is generally called *classified ads*. So any one of a, b, or c would be a *classified ad*. An online service like craigsList is a collection of classified ads. The term comes from the fact that they're organized into many different categories, so each of a, b, and c would likely be in different sections of the site.